# nftables changes on reboot

Tags: fedora, firewall, nftables

This is my `/etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf`

```
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f
flush ruleset
table ip filter {
    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        ct state established,related counter packets 264 bytes 17996 accept
        ct state invalid drop
        tcp dport 22 ip saddr 192.168.0.0/16 accept
        udp sport 53 accept
        drop
    }

    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
```

When I use `nft -f /etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf` but after I reboot, I also get these additional rules below the table I showed above:

```
table bridge filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
```

What is it that I do not understand?

Additional question. I'm trying to harden a machine. The machine should be used for essentially browsing the web, so that has to be allowed. And I want to be able to ssh to it from the local network. Have I missed something essential?

Comment: noticed that the command involved was actually ebtables (for bridge filtering) rather than iptables, so I edited the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the compatibility table and chains created by the newer version of the `ebtables` command, used to manipulate bridges, but using the *nftables* kernel API in *ebtables* compatibility mode.   Something ran an `ebtables` command somewhere, even if just to verify there's no *ebtables* rule present, or maybe to auto-load some *ebtables* ruleset, which was converted into an *nftables* ruleset.

You can know that's it by a few methods (here on CentOS8):

- actual executable

  ```
  # readlink -e /usr/sbin/ebtables
  /usr/sbin/xtables-nft-multi
  ```
- version displayed

  ```
  # ebtables -V
  ebtables 1.8.2 (nf_tables)
  ```
- rule monitoring

  term1:

  ```
  # nft -f /etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf
  # nft monitor #command waits in event mode
  ```

  term2:

  ```
  # ebtables -L
  Bridge table: filter

  Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

  Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

  Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT
  ```

  term 1 again (Fedora's newer *nftables* version would display a bridge's `-200` priority *value* with its *symbolic* equivalent `filter`):

  ```
  add table bridge filter
  add chain bridge filter INPUT { type filter hook input priority -200; policy accept; }
  add chain bridge filter FORWARD { type filter hook forward priority -200; policy accept; }
  add chain bridge filter OUTPUT { type filter hook output priority -200; policy accept; }
  # new generation 7 by process 16326 (ebtables)
  ```

As the base chains include no rules and have an *accept* policy, nothing will be affected. The system also requires the presence of a bridge to have this table and chains used at all anyway.

If CentOS8 and your current Fedora version are still close enough, this might be created by the use of the systemd *ebtables* service from the *iptables-ebtables* package. If you don't need bridge filtering, you can consider removing this package. You can still use *nft* for it if really needed.

The fact that the added table is of family *bridge* tells it's *ebtables* rather than *iptables*, *ip6tables* or *arptables* which would all give the same behaviour, creating if not already present a different table family (resp. *ip*, *ip6* or *arp*) and its base chains. So one should avoid using the same table names to avoid any clash, or at least not the same table+chain combination (eg: an *nft* rule in the `ip filter INPUT` (uppercase) chain could clash with *iptables* etc.)

more informations about this here:

[Moving from iptables to nftables - nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Moving_from_iptables_to_nftables#using_the_nf_tables_compat_backend)

[Legacy xtables tools - nftables wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Legacy_xtables_tools)

[Using iptables-nft: a hybrid Linux firewall - Red Hat](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/using-iptables-nft-hybrid-linux-firewall)

---

About the additional question:

Your rules appear to allow basic client usage (including SSH access from LAN), one important exception notwithstanding:

```
udp sport 53 accept
```

will allow to access *any* UDP port of your system, as long as the "scan" is made from UDP source port 53.

Replace it with this more sensible rule:

```
iif lo accept
```

to allow local communication unhindered (including a possible local DNS server).

Comment: Are you suggesting simply uninstalling iptables?

Comment: no, suggesting to ignore this and move on. I also addressed your additional question.

Comment: Ok thanks, but what does those additional rules actually do?

Comment: They just do nothing: empty tables and chains with no rules. You will have to read on nftables documentation to understand the differences with iptables. One important difference is that *tables* are not fixed: you can create as many as you want. A packet will traverse them all as long as it's not dropped (or for the special NAT case, not already NATed in the same hook)

Comment: I'll do some reading. But I'm not moving from iptables to nftables. I'm a beginner on both, and I have just installed a fresh Fedora and wanted to harden it.

Comment: Actually I didn't check well the added chain: the command used wasn't iptables but ebtables. Beside, everything told applies. I will edit my answer